# ¿Cómo optener la variable de php?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Cómo saco la variable **price_usd** de este link:
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

Aqui sale lo siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "7421.41699859", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "17195990125.7", 
        "market_cap_usd": "134228386222", 
        "available_supply": "18086625.0", 
        "total_supply": "18086625.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.0", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.76", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-3.64", 
        "last_updated": "1575649418"
    }
]
```

Yo quisiera el valor *price_usd* si alguien me ayuda a hacer `echo` o `print` de ese valor único para hacer cálculos matemáticos lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde PHP puedes leer los datos tanto mediante `cURL` como mediante `file_get_contents`. Cabe decir que `cURL` es más completo, más seguro y más potente.

Veamos un código de ejemplo con ambas posibilidades. Podrás verificar una demostración en línea.

```
<?php
    /*Con file_get_contents*/
    $url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/',true);
    $json=json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    echo "Con file_get_contents: $price_usd";
    echo "<hr>";;

    /*Con curl*/
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"utf-8");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "Con curl: $price_usd";
?>
```

**Salida:**

```
Con file_get_contents: 7509.56593448

Con curl: 7509.56593448
```

---

**<kbd>[DEMOSTRACIÓN EN PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3jaw-mcpg)</kbd>**

Pulsa en **`Run-F9`** para ver el código funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

el dato lo puede obtener así.

```
<?php

$apiUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/';
$curl = curl_init($apiUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($curl);

$array = json_decode($json);

$price_usd = $array[0]->price_usd;

echo $price_usd;

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: amigo eso es con las etiquetas <?php contenido del post ?> ? por que me dio este error (Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coint.php on line 7)

Comment: Le faltan librerías al OP

Comment: Yo lo probè en XAMPP y me corrió normal.

Comment: XAMPP viene preconfigurado y el OP sólo indica PHP. Puede tener un LAMP configurado diferente. Amplía tu respuesta indicando cómo habilitar el uso de `curl_init`

Comment: yo uso xampp 5.3 y no me corrio

Comment: ya habilite extension=php_curl.dll no me da error pero no me imprime el resultado ¿por que?

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
$arrayContextOptions = [
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ]
];

$json_data = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/', false, stream_context_create($arrayContextOptions));
$data = json_decode($json_data);
$price_usd = $data[0]->price_usd;
echo $price_usd;
```

**file_get_contents()** es bastante sencillo de usar, ideal para simples solicitudes **GET** donde no tienes que configurar algún parámetro.

Mas sin en cambio **curl** es mas completo para realizar solicitudes a otros servidores donde tendrías que hacer una configuración extra (por ejemplo: autenticación para obtener los datos de esa url).

PD: Utiliza la que mas se acomode a tu desarrollo y necesidades

Comment: me dio estos errores no logro conectar no se si es mi xampp o que pero no me deja conectar

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coint.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Failed to enable crypto in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coint.php on line 2

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coint.php on line 2

Comment: Eso debería de corregir tu problema con el SSL

Comment: lo estoy haciendo desde una PC localhost de mi casa

Comment: en tal caso como se corrige?

Comment: lo estoy haciendo en xampp php 5.3